# simple checkout from svn via javahl

Tags: java, svn

I want to use javahl to checkout sources from svn from within a java program.
Trying Javahl because it seems to be free, also for commercial use.

I need to checkout something like http://example.com/svn/project1/trunk to a local directory.

That should be a rather straight-forward process, just a few lines of code? Still i couldnt find any tutorials on how to do that.

Could you give some example java lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question is old, but I had to do something similar today.  I also couldn't find any good tutorials and ended up using the [unit tests](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subclipse/javahl/master/src/test/java/org/apache/subversion/javahl/SVNTests.java) as my reference.

Here's some Java code that worked for me:

```
import org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException;
import org.apache.subversion.javahl.SVNClient;
import org.apache.subversion.javahl.types.Depth;
import org.apache.subversion.javahl.types.Revision;
...
static void checkout(String reproUrl, String workingDirectory) throws ClientException {
    SVNClient client = new SVNClient();
    client.checkout(
        reproUrl,
        workingDirectory,
        Revision.HEAD,
        Revision.HEAD,
        Depth.infinity,
        false,
        false);
}
```

And if you need to authenticate, `SVNClient` has `username(String)` and `password(String)` methods.

Answer (score -3):

look 
http://wiki.svnkit.com/Getting_Started_With_SVNKit 
and 
http://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_A_Working_Copy

```
private static long checkout( SVNURL url , SVNRevision revision , File destPath , boolean isRecursive ) throws SVNException {

   SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient( );
   /*
    * sets externals not to be ignored during the checkout
     */
    updateClient.setIgnoreExternals( false );
    /*
     * returns the number of the revision at which the working copy is 
    */
   return updateClient.doCheckout( url , destPath , revision , revision , isRecursive );
```

}

Comment: But that is svnkit, is there a way to just use javahl?

Comment: This answer shouldn't be marked as correct or the best since, unfortunately it doesn't answer the question. The question talks about JavaHL and this answer is about SVNKit

Comment: Answer shoulod be related to javahl rather then svnkit. both are different.